# Why we need AZure Devops Yaml template extends?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

**My issue**

Yaml Devops propose the **extends** bloc. This is the kind of sample one use:

```
# main.yaml
 
trigger: none
 
extends:
  template: ./extends-pipeline1.yaml
```

And:

```
# extends-pipeline1.yaml
 
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: echo Build solution
 
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: echo Deploy solution
```

Works fine, but this works as well without **extends**:

```
# main.yaml

trigger: none

stages:
  - template: extends-pipeline1.yaml
```

**What I did**

I read the release note:

[Release Note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-162-update#use-extends-keyword-in-pipelines?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5004831)

**My question**

What is the benefit to use **extends**?

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#extend-from-a-template

Comment: yes, but the provided sample works without extends. It just fails at start instead of when running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the benefit to use extends?

There are two benefits of this feature.

## First, 'extends' is more free than 'stages'.

When you use stages, then the pipeline will expect stages in the template, you must write the stages part in the template, otherwise the validation step will not be passed.

**For example, when you use stages, your pipeline must be like this:**

***azure-pipelines.yml***

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - template: extends-pipeline1.yaml
```

***extends-pipeline1.yaml***

```
stages: #You must have this section in the template.
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: echo Build solution
 
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: echo Deploy solution
```

**But if you use extends, your pipeline could be like this instead of must writing stages section in template:**

***azure-pipelines.yml***

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

extends:
  template: extends-pipeline1.yaml
```

***extends-pipeline1.yaml***

```
jobs:
- job:
  steps:
  - script: echo Build solution
```

## Second, 'extends' has a feature named [Required template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#required-template).(Daniel had already mentioned this.)

If you set the 'required template' of the service connection, then the service connection will only been able to use in specific YAML template file which been 'extends'.

No matter directly use the service connection via main YAML file or use the service connection in the YAML file referred via 'stages'-template will both make the pipeline failed.

This feature can help you increase the security and this feature is exclusive to the 'extends' feature.